# Heroku routes not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, routes

So my main rails model is "Company". When I host my app locally and navigate to localhost:3000/companies, everything works fine. But when I navigate to the heroku version of my app at:

http://calm-journey-2877.herokuapp.com/companies

.. I get the error "We're sorry but something went wrong"

This indicates that the page exists but is producing some sort of error.. Any idea what could be happening? This is a very basic app that I built by reading the Rails Tutorial Book.

Thanks!!

Edit:

Here's the Heroku log.

```
2012-08-29T22:20:54+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:38:in `receive_data'
2012-08-29T22:20:54+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
2012-08-29T22:20:54+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run'
2012-08-29T22:20:54+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
2012-08-29T22:20:54+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run_machine'
2012-08-29T22:20:54+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:185:in `run_command'
2012-08-29T22:20:54+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:86:in `start'
2012-08-29T22:20:54+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:151:in `run!'
2012-08-29T22:20:54+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `load'
2012-08-29T22:20:54+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `<main>'
2012-08-29T22:20:54+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-08-29T22:20:54+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2012-08-29T22:20:54+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-08-29T22:20:54+00:00 heroku[router]: GET calm-journey-2877.herokuapp.com/clients dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=7ms status=404 bytes=728
2012-08-29T22:21:00+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-08-29T22:21:00+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-08-29T22:21:00+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/companies" for 24.14.103.65 at 2012-08-29 22:21:00 +0000
2012-08-29T22:21:00+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by CompaniesController#index as HTML
2012-08-29T22:21:00+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms
2012-08-29T22:21:00+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-08-29T22:21:00+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "companies" does not exist
2012-08-29T22:21:00+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 4:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"companies"'::regclass
2012-08-29T22:21:00+00:00 app[web.1]:                                         ^
2012-08-29T22:21:00+00:00 app[web.1]: :             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
2012-08-29T22:21:00+00:00 app[web.1]:               FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
2012-08-29T22:21:00+00:00 app[web.1]:                 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
2012-08-29T22:21:00+00:00 app[web.1]:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"companies"'::regclass
2012-08-29T22:21:00+00:00 app[web.1]:                AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
2012-08-29T22:21:00+00:00 app[web.1]:              ORDER BY a.attnum
2012-08-29T22:21:00+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2012-08-29T22:21:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/companies_controller.rb:86:in `sort_column'
2012-08-29T22:21:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/companies_controller.rb:6:in `index'
2012-08-29T22:21:00+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-08-29T22:21:00+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-08-29T22:21:00+00:00 heroku[router]: GET calm-journey-2877.herokuapp.com/companies dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=13ms status=500 bytes=643
2012-08-29T22:21:00+00:00 heroku[router]: GET calm-journey-2877.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=0
2012-08-29T22:27:31+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-08-29T22:27:31+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-08-29T22:27:31+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/companies" for 24.14.103.65 at 2012-08-29 22:27:31 +0000
2012-08-29T22:27:31+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by CompaniesController#index as HTML
2012-08-29T22:27:31+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 14ms
2012-08-29T22:27:31+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-08-29T22:27:31+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 4:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"companies"'::regclass
2012-08-29T22:27:31+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "companies" does not exist
2012-08-29T22:27:31+00:00 app[web.1]:                                         ^
2012-08-29T22:27:31+00:00 app[web.1]: :             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
2012-08-29T22:27:31+00:00 app[web.1]:               FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
2012-08-29T22:27:31+00:00 app[web.1]:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"companies"'::regclass
2012-08-29T22:27:31+00:00 app[web.1]:                 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
2012-08-29T22:27:31+00:00 app[web.1]:                AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
2012-08-29T22:27:31+00:00 app[web.1]:              ORDER BY a.attnum
2012-08-29T22:27:31+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2012-08-29T22:27:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/companies_controller.rb:86:in `sort_column'
2012-08-29T22:27:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/companies_controller.rb:6:in `index'
2012-08-29T22:27:31+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-08-29T22:27:31+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-08-29T22:27:31+00:00 heroku[router]: GET calm-journey-2877.herokuapp.com/companies dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=42ms status=500 bytes=643
2012-08-29T22:27:31+00:00 heroku[router]: GET calm-journey-2877.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=0
2012-08-29T22:29:13+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-08-29T22:29:13+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-08-29T22:29:13+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/companies" for 24.14.103.65 at 2012-08-29 22:29:13 +0000
2012-08-29T22:29:13+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by CompaniesController#index as HTML
2012-08-29T22:29:13+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms
2012-08-29T22:29:13+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-08-29T22:29:13+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 4:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"companies"'::regclass
2012-08-29T22:29:13+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "companies" does not exist
2012-08-29T22:29:13+00:00 app[web.1]: :             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
2012-08-29T22:29:13+00:00 app[web.1]:                                         ^
2012-08-29T22:29:13+00:00 app[web.1]:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"companies"'::regclass
2012-08-29T22:29:13+00:00 app[web.1]:               FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
2012-08-29T22:29:13+00:00 app[web.1]:                 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
2012-08-29T22:29:13+00:00 app[web.1]:                AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
2012-08-29T22:29:13+00:00 app[web.1]:              ORDER BY a.attnum
2012-08-29T22:29:13+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2012-08-29T22:29:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/companies_controller.rb:6:in `index'
2012-08-29T22:29:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/companies_controller.rb:86:in `sort_column'
2012-08-29T22:29:13+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-08-29T22:29:13+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-08-29T22:29:13+00:00 heroku[router]: GET calm-journey-2877.herokuapp.com/companies dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=10ms status=500 bytes=643
2012-08-29T22:33:52+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-08-29T22:33:52+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-08-29T22:33:52+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/companies" for 186.147.240.150 at 2012-08-29 22:33:52 +0000
2012-08-29T22:33:52+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by CompaniesController#index as HTML
2012-08-29T22:33:52+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms
2012-08-29T22:33:52+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-08-29T22:33:52+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "companies" does not exist
2012-08-29T22:33:52+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 4:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"companies"'::regclass
2012-08-29T22:33:52+00:00 app[web.1]:                                         ^
2012-08-29T22:33:52+00:00 app[web.1]:               FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
2012-08-29T22:33:52+00:00 app[web.1]: :             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
2012-08-29T22:33:52+00:00 app[web.1]:                 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
2012-08-29T22:33:52+00:00 app[web.1]:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"companies"'::regclass
2012-08-29T22:33:52+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-08-29T22:33:52+00:00 app[web.1]:              ORDER BY a.attnum
2012-08-29T22:33:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/companies_controller.rb:86:in `sort_column'
2012-08-29T22:33:52+00:00 app[web.1]:                AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
2012-08-29T22:33:52+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2012-08-29T22:33:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/companies_controller.rb:6:in `index'
2012-08-29T22:33:52+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-08-29T22:33:52+00:00 heroku[router]: GET calm-journey-2877.herokuapp.com/companies dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=10ms status=500 bytes=643
2012-08-29T22:33:52+00:00 heroku[router]: GET calm-journey-2877.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=0
```

Comment: Look at the error log on Heroku to see what went wrong, i.e. `heroku logs`.  This might point you in the right direction.  It might be unrelated to routing, e.g. you may have forgotten to build and migrate your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you migrate database in Heroku `heroku run rake db:migrate`?

Comment: Thank you! This seems to have helped a bit. However, it didn't migrate everything.. is there anyway to migrate all six of my migrations? Sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm really new to rails.

Comment: how do you know it didn't run all of your migrations?

Comment: Ok, I think I figured out what happened. I imported data into the database directly from a CSV file using a rake task. Since this task imported the data directly into the database, a migration file was not created. I just need to somehow create a migration file from the rake task.

Comment: You could run `heroku run rake 'the_task_that_uses_the_csv_file'`

Answer (score 0):

Your solution rest in git. Write your rake task and make sure it's in your git repository.

Than try
    Heroku run rake your_task

That or use your DB seed file for its intended purpose.